# Mod-rewrite URL in PHP

Tags: php, apache

I use urls like

```
http://example.com/video.php?v=foo-bla
```

but i want this

```
http://example.com/video/foo-bla.html
```

i'm trying this code..

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule videos/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)/? video.php?v=$1 [NC]
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried and explain why it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: i'm trying this
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule videos/([-A-Za-z0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/? video.php?v=$1 [NC]